# How to change the background color of a transparent desktop image on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, colors, desktop

Under **Desktop & Screen Saver** I have selected to show a PNG image with transparency on my Desktop. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The transparent area shows the exact same color that is listed as the first solid color under **Apple -> Solid Colors**. I tried changing the solid color to something else, then select the image again, hoping it would remember the last solid color selection. But after selecting an image it always reverts back to showing the blue-ish color as the transparent area of the image. I would very much like to change the background color of the image's transparent area.

How can I change the background color of transparent desktop images? Is it even possible?

Comment: I know I could just modify the image itself. But I'm wondering if there's a system-wide setting for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argh. Just after asking the question I figured it out!

First, select either **Center** or **Fit to Screen** from the selection above the image thumbnail view. To the right a color selection button will appear.

Now change that color to whatever you want, then set the selection back to **Tile** or any of the other settings that don't support changing the background color. The selected background color will still be used for the transparent areas of the image.

Comment: …ran into the exact same trap. Didn't know how to change the color. Thank you for sharing the solution so I can immediately stop searching. ;)